# My pagination creates a redirect

Tags: redirect, pagination

Can you help me this time to fix this problem

my code is:

```
public function numeric_pagination() {
        global  $wp_query , $wp_rewrite;;
        if ( $wp_query->max_num_pages < 2 ) {
            return;
        }
        $paged        = get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? intval( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) : 1;
        $pagenum_link = html_entity_decode( get_pagenum_link() );
        $total        = isset( $wp_query->max_num_pages ) ? $wp_query->max_num_pages : 1;
        $url_parts    = explode( '?', $pagenum_link );
        $pagenum_link = trailingslashit( $url_parts[0] ) . '%_%';
        $format       = $wp_rewrite->using_index_permalinks() && ! strpos( $pagenum_link, 'index.php' ) ? 'index.php/' : '';
        $format      .= $wp_rewrite->using_permalinks() ? user_trailingslashit( $wp_rewrite->pagination_base . '/%#%', 'paged' ) : '?paged=%#%';
        $links = paginate_links( array(
            'base'     => $pagenum_link,
            'format'   => $format,
            'total'    => $wp_query->max_num_pages,
            'current'  => $paged,
            'total'    => $total,
            'mid_size' => 1,
            'prev_text' => '«',
            'next_text' => '»',
            'type'      => 'array',
        ) );
        if( is_array( $links ) ) {
            $pagination  = '<div class="pagination-wrap"><ol class="pagination">';
            foreach ( $links as $page_key => $page) {
                $pagination .= "<li>$page</li>";
            }
            $pagination .= '</ol></div>';
            return $pagination;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

and my problem is
At the end the category main page link gives a "/" which causes redirection 301

example:
mysite.com/category/ -> redirect to mysite.com/category

i need remove / in category main page

The rest of the pages are correct
example:
mysite.com/category/page/2

mysite.com/category/page/3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove the trailing slash from the pagination links by adding [`untrailingslashit()` function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/untrailingslashit/) as callback for [`paginate_links` filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/paginate_links/).

Put this code in your theme's `functions.php` or in an mu-plugin (untested):

```php
add_filter( 'paginate_links', 'untrailingslashit' );
```